# Combining two LAN networks (newbie)

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, lan, gateway

[image]To start off, I just wanna mention that I am a newbie when it comes to networking, so some terms or descriptions might be wrong.

The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to merge two LAN networks since one of the computers in our family is not connected to the same LAN network as the other, preventing us from playing games in LAN mode without programs like e.g. hamachi. I've tried to visualize the situation in the image in the link below:

So R1 is the CPE (cts hes 3106) that provides all the other entities with ethernet, I'm assuming this is called a gateway. Now C and B will have the same internal ip adress due to R2 (Technicolor 799 Xtream, which I assume acts as a router), whereas A will have the WAN ip from R1. Can I make it so that A, B and C share the same LAN, so that we can play games together in LAN. I can't rewire A into R2 and if possible I would like to solve this without buying an additional router.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svwkB.png)

Comment: Welcome. Can you provide clarifications - what is preventing you from rewiring A into R2? Is it purely a cabling thing or are there IP addressing / security constraints?  Please advise make and models for R1and R2. When you say A will have the same WAN address as R2, how have you ascertained this (it is extremely unlikely).  Is it permissible to simplify your network architecture and change IP addresses in the LAN?

Comment: Relatedly, how many LAN ports do R1 and R2 have, and ate there more then 3 devices connected in actuality?

Comment: If the networks are physically located in the same place, connect a LAN port on Router 2 to a LAN port in Router 1, and give Router 2 a static IP on Router 1. Turn DHCP OFF on Router 2.  If locations are separated then you need a VPN connection or equivalent.

Comment: @davidgo I can't rewire due to cabling issues (under floor tiles). I've added the models for R1 and R2 now. Relating to the WAN address, I checked which WAN ip R2 has and it says: 83.2**.**.*** whereas if I check the ip with ipconfig for computer A, I get 84.2**.**.*** so I assumed it was somehow related, but once again I am a complete newbie and only know certain pieces of information. I don't know what you mean by simplify network architecture, but I think I can change the IP adresses of the LAN for R2 in https//192.168.10.1. It says that DCHP is enabled which I don't know what that means.

Comment: @davidgo I think both of them have about 6 ports if I'm not mistaken. For R1 it's only the R2 router and the A computer that is connected, whereas in R2 B and C computers are connected together with other devices like TV, ps4 and other things.

Comment: You should be able to log into the router interface and change both the LAN address and also change DHCP to OFF on router 2. This seems workable if you can properly identify cables.

Comment: @John They are separated but I could connect them. How do I give it a static IP? Is this done in https//192.168.10.1?

Comment: Go to the LAN interface on Router 2 and set that to an IP address from Router 1 that is not part of Router 1’s DHCP range.

Comment: @John What do I change the LAN address to? And do I change it in R1 or R2?

Comment: Leave R1 alone. Just look at the setting for LAN. DHCP range will be shown. Set R2 LAN IP to a value outside of that

Comment: @John - can I handle this one?  I am fairly sure I understand what is going on, and that to do this will practically require minor recabling changes as well.

Comment: I can leave it to you. I was not trying to intrude upon you, rather just help the user as there are some setup issues as well as cabling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to simplify your network.  You can do this by making some simple cabling changes and reconfiguring a router.  The solution I'm proposing is called flattending the network - the outcome should look as follows:

[image]

Effectively this means that we will be converting R2 into a switch / Access Point and having R1 do all the routing.    You can do this without any additional cabling.

(Please read and understand the below before you implement it)
The steps involved are:

- (To be safe) Log in to R2 and find the range of IP addresses set aside for DHCP.  This is likely going to be something starting at 192.168.10.100 - If its not, let me know what it is, but I'll work on this assumption for now.
- Log in to R2 (from B or C or another device connected on its LAN).  Turn off DHCP and reconfigure the LAN IP address to 192.168.10.2   (I expect it will be 192.168.x.x, or maybe 10.x.x.x or 100.x.x.x).  Save these changes.   You have now, in effect, turned R2 into little more then an Access point or switch.
- At R2 end, move the cable that runs from the WAN port (which goes to R2) to a LAN port.
- Reboot R2 and disconnect and reconnect any WIFI devices that connect to R2 or reboot them.  This is to force everything to get a new IP address (which will now be provided by R1).

Everything will now be on the same LAN and should be able to talk to everything else directly.   If you need to reconfigure R2 for any reason you will now do so by going to 192.168.10.2.   (You may want to write this address on the bottom of the router, as its easy to forget, and it is difficult to find the device in your network as it will no longer appear in traceroutes or routing tables.

Comment: Before you do this, can you show the routing table of device A.  (open a command window and type route I think).  Under linux it would be opening a terminal and typing sudo ip route show  - I am somewhat concerned about your comment  says: 83.2**.**.*** whereas if I check the ip with ipconfig for computer A, I get 84.2**.**.***

Comment: Can you confirm that your network is a standard home network?

Comment: Yes it's a standard home network. After typing "route print -4" I get that the gateway is 84.2**.2**.1  (I'm not sure how secretive I have to be with this address which is why I include the *'s). I'll try the steps you've provided now and will be back shortly.

Comment: One thing, in the DHCP settings it says that the DNS server is 192.168.10.2, should I still change the LAN IP to 192.168.10.2 ?

Comment: While reading about DHCP and trying to understand it a bit more I read a piece of text that said "It's [static IP] more expensive than a dynamic IP address because ISP often charges an additional fee for static IP addresses. Is this something that is relevant in this case?

Comment: Well l tried it and while it changed my ipv4 address to 84.2**.1**.68 it didn't allow me to play LAN mode with computer A, who has ipv4 address 83.2**.2**.197

Comment: Please set things back how they were. Something is very, very wrong with your setup.

Comment: Well I'm trying to do that. but I don't seem to be able to connect to R2 anymore. Can't access it either through 192.168.10.2 or 192.168.10.1 How would I change it back?

Comment: I suspect what you are calling r2 is a cable modem on an incorrectly setup land with an incompetent ISP.   To help you further, I really need to know the make and model of both R1 and R2.  It appears you are using non-local IP addresses and are bridging your lan and wan. Your ISP seems incompetent for allowing this and you are opening your computer up to direct attack from the wider internet.

Comment: You may want to get your ISP involved.  Before that though you can try manually setting device A's IP to 192.186.10.3 netmask 255.255.0.0 and see if you can access 192.168.10.1/2

Comment: I reset the r2 which seems to have fixed that part at least. The description of the R2 says that it's a router, the model is Technicolor TG799vac Xtream. For R1 the model is cts HES-3106. Is it just the A computer that is unsafe then or is it all of them? What would I need to get fixed?

Comment: The R1 seems to be a switch and not a router.

Comment: You should speak to your ISP. R1 appears to be CPE - which means its likely controlled by your ISP and is not a standard switch (it appears to carry other non Ethernet services and is managed).  Your setup appears very non-standard which means any help we provide is likely to cause more problems then it solves.

Comment: Alright, I'll try calling them. Thanks for all the help provided and I'm sorry if I made it harder by not correctly identifying all the parts. Once again I'm a complete newbie and all I really wanted was to play LAN together with my family :).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to buy a cheap unmanaged switch ($20 will get you one) and simply use that switch to replace R2 completely.

Other than that follow Davidgo's instructions which basically tell you to reconfigure R2 to act like such an unmanaged switch.

My suggestion (the real switch) has the benefit that you don't need to do any configuration, so there is no change for getting it wrong. It is just plug and play.

Comment: I guess instead of buying a new switch he could just reconfigure R2 to not provide routing capabilities?

Comment: @jvda That's what I said in the 2nd line didn't I? But that reconfiguration can be complicated and (in some routers) not even possible (I've seen some where you can't disable the DHCP). As the poster mentioned to be a complete novice at this I figured it couldn't hurt to give him a option that doesn't require complicated configuration.